# npm install doesn't install any dependencies

Tags: node.js

I am trying to install packages in the `package.json` file.  Unfortunately, when I run `npm install`, nothing happens (nothing is installed).  I have used `npm install` on other repos and it works successfully.

Here is my path:

```
$PATH = /Users/me/.rbenv/shims:/Users/me/.rbenv/bin:/usr/local/share/npm/bin:/usr/local/bin:/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

As you can see, `npm/bin` is in my bath and I believe this is correct.

Here are the instructions for this repo and where to run npm install (which I am doing)

```
go into "module"
run "npm install"
pair your laptop/pc with intelligent brick troubleshoot: http://www.ev-3.net/en/archives/97
run example.js: "node example.js"
see "example.js" for more details
```

When I run npm install in the module directory (that has the package.json) nothing installs.

Here is the package.json:

```
{
  "name": "ev3-nodejs-bt",
  "description": "Bt Api for lego ev3 robot",
  "version": "0.0.4",
  "private": false,
  "dependencies": {
    "serialport": "1.*"
  },
  "main": "Ev3.js",
  "devDependencies": {"serialport": "1.*"},
  "scripts": {
    "test": "node Ev3.js"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/wenchaojiang/Ev3NodeJsBtAPI"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "node.js",
    "ev3",
    "lego",
    "robot",
    "bluetooth"
  ],
  "author": "Wenchao Jiang <psxwj@nottingham.ac.uk> (http://wenchaojames.wordpress.com/)",
  "license": "MIT",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/wenchaojiang/Ev3NodeJsBtAPI/issues"
  }
}
```

Do I have something set up wrong on my system? (I don't think I do based on my $PATH and successful installing packets in other node-js repos) Is this package.json file not valid?

Comment: Node JS and Legos?  Sign me up!

Comment: The only dependency I see is "serialport".  What are the contents of your `node_modules` directory?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`npm install` doesn't install (or echo) anything when all of the dependencies are satisfied.  Ensure there's a `serialport` folder under `node_modules`.

If you want to reinstall everything, you just need to remove the `node_modules` folder:

```
rm -r node_modules
npm install
```

Comment: Very sorry, Not sure why the quotes were not included when I copied/pasted. In my package.json file, they do have quotes as you mentioned. I just updated the file in the questions.

Comment: Alright, JSONLint says you've got valid JSON, and I was able to `npm install` using the same package.json.  Is there a `node_modules` folder in the directory?

Comment: @SomeKittens, I am having the same problem as HelloWorld, but deleting the node_modules directory and re-running npm install is still leaving me high and dry.  I run npm install, and it lists all the dependencies that were installed (according to my package.json), but after running npm install, there still is no directory made called "node_modules", and consequently nothing gets installed.  I can run this again and again and get the same results.  I'd like to see if there are other solutions to this mystery.

Comment: @CtheGood I'd ask a new question with the code in question.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an npm-shrinkwrap.json file, check it. The `npm install` command will only install the packages specified in that file.

According to the [`npm install` docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install):

> If the package has a shrinkwrap file, the installation of dependencies will be driven by that.

I had the same problem with my project. And when I looked at my npm-shrinkwrap.json file, I saw `dependencies: {}`. So that's why it didn't install anything for me.