# NPM install does not install any dependencies from package.json

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json

I am trying to run **npm install** from the root of my Node.js project, because I want to install all of my project dependencies located in my **package.json**.  However, when I run **npm install** in the command line, it shows a list of the dependencies that it reportedly installed, however when I go to that directory and search for the subdirectory **node_modules/**, it does not exist.  Therefore, those dependencies were not really installed, as is evidenced when I try to run **npm start**, it will start throwing errors about modules missing.  What am I doing wrong?

This is a copy of my **package.json** (specifics removed for privacy):

```
{
  "name": "xxxxxxxxx",
  "version": "x.x.x",
  "description": "xxxxxxxxx",
  "main": "xxxxxxxxx.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node xxxxxxxxx.js",
    "lint": "jshint **/**/*.js --reporter=node_modules/jshint-stylish/stylish.js",
    "test": "mocha test/"
  },
  "pre-commit": [
    "lint",
    "test"
  ],
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://xxxxxxxxx.git"
  },
  "author": "xxxxxxxxx",
  "license": "xxxxxxxxx",
  "dependencies": {
    "bluebird": "^2.9.13",
    "boom": "^2.6.1",
    "good": "^5.1.2",
    "good-console": "^4.1.0",
    "hapi": "^8.2.0",
    "hapi-swagger": "^0.6.4",
    "joi": "^5.1.0",
    "lodash": "^3.3.1",
    "lodash-deep": "^1.5.3",
    "lout": "^6.2.0",
    "request": "^2.55.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "chai": "^2.0.0",
    "jshint-stylish": "^1.0.2",
    "mocha": "^2.1.0",
    "pre-commit": "^1.0.7"
  }
}
```

As noted, all of the dependencies listed here show up in command prompt with the green text, indicating to me that they were downloaded.  However, they were not downloaded, as the **node_modules/** does not even exist.  The command prompt looks like this:

```
C:\development>npm install
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/boom
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/good-console
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/bluebird
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/good
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/joi
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/hapi-swagger
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/lout
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/hapi
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/lodash-deep
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/chai
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/lodash
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/jshint-stylish
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mocha
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/pre-commit
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/request
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/good-console
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/boom
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/bluebird
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/good
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/hapi-swagger
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/hapi
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/lodash-deep
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/chai
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/joi
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/lodash
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/lout
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/jshint-stylish
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/mocha
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/pre-commit
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/request

C:\development>ll
05/13/2015  12:32 PM    <DIR>          .
05/13/2015  12:32 PM    <DIR>          ..
05/12/2015  05:24 PM                93 .gitignore
05/12/2015  05:24 PM                15 .jshintignore
05/12/2015  05:24 PM             3,957 .jshintrc
05/12/2015  05:24 PM                36 .npmrc
05/12/2015  05:24 PM    <DIR>          config
05/12/2015  05:24 PM             1,363 xxxxx.json
05/12/2015  05:24 PM    <DIR>          lib
05/12/2015  05:24 PM             1,201 package.json
05/12/2015  05:24 PM             1,113 readme.md
05/12/2015  05:24 PM             2,046 xxxxx.js

C:\development>npm start

module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'hapi'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\path)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
```

Notice above that no subdirectory **node_modules/** exists above, as well as the fact that it cannot find the module **'hapi'** when it was listed in the command prompt earlier as having been downloaded.

What I have tried so far is:

- Manually creating the **node_modules/** directory before running **npm install**
- Checking directory permissions
- Other stackoverflow articles

But I have still had no success.  Note that the closest stackoverflow to my question is [npm install doesn't install any dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23302357/npm-install-doesnt-install-any-dependencies), but this differs in the fact that the "answer" on that post does not solve my problem (which was to delete the directory **node_modules/**, but mine doesn't even exist).

I am able to run **npm install** in other Node.js projects that I have, with success in installing dependencies from their **package.json**.  I just can't get this example to work.

Comment: Can you see installed dependencies using `npm ls` ? Looks like `npm install` is interrupted by some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Watch for root folder in npmrc.. May be all your dependencies are downloaded to root folder.. Npm does this some times.. I too encountered this problem... Mostly it happens when no package.json file in the folder.. 2nd would be from your logs I don't see the modules downloaded info.. May it couldn't access npm or some thing.. Set npm registry comfig to http and try once again. Change your path D: or some thing.. If it happens there raise a bug with npm