# NPM installs no dependencies

Tags: iis, npm, windows-10

When I run `npm install`, a `node_modules` folder is created, but no modules are installed. This happens regardless of where the project folder is located. I don't see any helpful output from a verbose run of the command. I have referenced [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23302357/npm-install-doesnt-install-any-dependencies?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30223199/npm-install-does-not-install-any-dependencies-from-package-json?noredirect=1&lq=1), both of which are similar but don't apply here. Is there something I need to do or change to have `npm install` run successfully in this environment?

The output of `npm install --verbose`:

```
npm info it worked if it ends with ok
npm verb cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
npm verb cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
npm verb cli   'install',
npm verb cli   '--verbose' ]
npm info using npm@3.10.10
npm info using node@v6.11.3
npm info lifecycle undefined~preinstall: undefined
npm verb correctMkdir C:\Users\btm296\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_locks correctMkdir not in flight; initializing
npm verb lock using C:\Users\btm296\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_locks\staging-7d19d75cf02aa2ec.lock for C:\inetpub\wwwroot\photo\web\themes\custom\byu_photo\node_modules\.staging
npm verb unlock done using C:\Users\btm296\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_locks\staging-7d19d75cf02aa2ec.lock for C:\inetpub\wwwroot\photo\web\themes\custom\byu_photo\node_modules\.staging
npm info linkStuff !invalid#1
npm verb linkBins !invalid#1
npm verb linkMans !invalid#1
npm info lifecycle undefined~install: undefined
npm info lifecycle undefined~postinstall: undefined
npm info lifecycle undefined~prepublish: undefined
npm info ok
```

And the dependecies part of package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.7",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-autoprefixer": "^3.1.1",
    "gulp-clean-css": "^3.8.0",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.1",
    "gulp-inject": "^4.2.0",
    "gulp-minify": "^1.0.0",
    "gulp-notify": "^2.2.0",
    "gulp-sass": "^3.1.0",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^2.6.1",
    "slick-carousel": "^1.6.0"
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to run `npm install` in the folder that contains `package.json`.

Comment: I've already done that. That's where this issue is originating from.